# What is the relationship of TypeMirrors and Elements in the lang model?

Tags: annotation-processing

(While this question is tagged with `annotation-processing` I'm actually asking questions about the type model exposed by `javax.lang.model` whether or not annotation processing is involved.)

In `javax.lang.model`, there are two fundamental constructs: [`Element`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html) and [`TypeMirror`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html).

[Every `Element` is backed by a `TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType()).  However only certain `TypeMirror` subtypes, namely [`DeclaredType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html) and [`TypeVariable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeVariable.html), have `Element`s associated with them via [`DeclaredType#asElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html#asElement()) and [`TypeVariable#asElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeVariable.html#asElement()) respectively.

(It follows that all `Element`s "have" `TypeMirror`s, but not all `TypeMirror`s "have" `Element`s.)

Speaking loosely and intuitively, this makes sense: you declare types by chanting certain Java spells: the spells themselves are the (declared) elements; the things they bring into being are the types that back them.  I've programmed in Java for decades and have a good working familiarity with oddities like `Foo implements Comparable<Foo>`.  I'm trying to get more rigorous here.

With all that in mind, and considering the following snippet, how are the `javax.lang.model` types and elements manifested?

```java
// (Defined by the JDK itself of course.)
public interface Comparable<T> ...

// (My class.)
public class Frob implements Comparable<Frob> ...
```

I see the following "things", working from "top" to "bottom" with less and less certainty as I go along:

- a [`TypeParameterElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeParameterElement.html) whose [affiliated `Name`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getSimpleName()) is [equal to](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Name.html#contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)) "`T`"

  - The return value of its [`asType()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeParameterElement.html#asType()) will be a (definitionally nameless) [`TypeVariable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeVariable.html) whose [`asElement()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/TypeVariable.html#asElement()) will return the `TypeParameterElement` currently being discussed.
  - The return value of its [`getGenericElement()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeParameterElement.html#getGenericElement()) (and its [`getEnclosingElement()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeParameterElement.html#getEnclosingElement())) will be the `Element` we'll talk about next ("`Comparable`").
- a [`TypeElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html) whose [affiliated `Name`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getSimpleName()) is [equal to](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Name.html#contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)) "`Comparable`"

  - The return value of its [`asType()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#asType()) will be a (definitionally nameless) [`DeclaredType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html) whose [`asElement()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html#asElement()) will return the `TypeElement` currently being discussed

    - The `DeclaredType` so returned will [have exactly one type argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html#getTypeArguments()) which will be the (definitionally nameless) `TypeVariable` discussed above whose `asElement()` method will return the `TypeParameterElement` discussed above ("`T`")
  - The return value of its [`getTypeParameters()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getTypeParameters()) will consist solely of the `TypeParameterElement` discussed earlier.
- a `TypeElement` whose affiliated `Name` is equal to "`Frob`".

  - (This `TypeElement` is brought into being with the Java syntax `public class Frob ...`.)
  - The return value of its `asType()` method will be a (definitionally nameless) `DeclaredType` whose `asElement()` method will return the `TypeElement` currently being discussed.
  - The return value of its `getInterfaces()` method will be discussed in a moment.
- an `Element` of some variety loosely described by "`Comparable<Frob>`".

  - I say "of some variety" because as written it itself does not have, say, an explicit or implicit `extends` or `implements` clause, or other markers I would expect to see of, say, a `TypeElement`.  Nevertheless I'm not sure that it could be any other kind of `Element` other than a `TypeElement`.  Maybe it is a `TypeElement` equal to that denoted by "`Comparable<T>`", but with its various `TypeMirror`-returning or -referencing methods using the type denoted by `Frob`?
  - The return value of its `asType()` method will be a (definitionally nameless) `TypeMirror` of some variety (almost certainly a `DeclaredType`) whose `asElement()` method will return the `Element` currently being discussed (this corresponds somewhat to [`java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) in the runtime/reflection model)

    - The `TypeMirror` so returned will have exactly one type argument which will be the (definitionally nameless) `DeclaredType` returned by the `asType()` method of the `TypeElement` whose `Name` is equal to "`Frob`" described above
    - The `TypeMirror` so returned will be the sole member of the return value of the [`getInterfaces()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getInterfaces()) when invoked on the `TypeElement` whose `Name` is equal to "`Frob`" described above

Do I have this right as far as it goes?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems well-reasoned, and I can't find anything specifically wrong with it to point out to you, but it is missing the one vital truth of where Elements and TypeMirrors differ.

---

Elements represent nodes in the Java type AST that reside "on disk" - the code at rest, either in .java or .class files. Any class/interface/enum/record/annotation that exists on disk in this form is in some way discoverable by this. To get a bit further, these cover the entire API of any of those types above - any members (fields/constructors/methods or nested types, then also the params of those methods/ctors) and packages too are described by elements. But the Element hierarchy only covers the types on disk - to use a concrete example from your question, `Comparable<T>` and its `Comparable<T>.compareTo(T)` member, and that method's parameter are covered in this way. And yes, lest I omit the type parameter, both the class and the method have a type param embedded in their respective element - as an element.

On the other hand, TypeMirrors represent those elements "in use" - you can't really reason about `Comparable<T>` in your code, but instead will either use it raw (please don't), or will parameterize it in some specific way (such as `Comparable<Frob>`, `Comparable<?>`, or possibly `Comparable<T>` where `T` is the type param *of an enclosing element* such as the current method or class). This means that `T` is not the same TypeElement as above - it isn't the value of the `TypeElement` that was on disk, but is something more specific.

---

You'll find TypeMirrors in Elements (for example "what is the return type of the method that appears in this class?"), and all Elements can be converted to some form of TypeMirror. On the other hand, not all TypeMirrors can be converted to some Element (such as a primitive), or if they can, that conversion may be "lossy" (for example converting a TypeMirror of `List<String>` to an Element would give you only `List<T>` itself).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've noticed when I go spelunking through the actual javac `Types` class that, for example, things like `IntersectionClassType` (javac's internal representation of an `IntersectionType` from the lang model) have symbols (elements) where the lang model does not surface them. I wonder why not? Moreover, some logic in `Types` is predicated on whether certain types share exactly one symbol (like array types) or always have their own synthetic symbol (like wildcards if I remember right, particularly odd since a wildcard is not, in fact, in the JLS, a type at all).

Comment: I would personally avoid making assumption about implementation details in com.sun classes, as it is totally legal for a build tool to have its own implementation. For example, Eclipse's JDT reimplements all of this differently (beware using Element.toString()), and Gradle changes up some of the details in other classes for the sake of incremental builds.

Comment: Thanks; yes, I understand. I however believe archaeology always has something to teach us. In this case: the lang model clearly emerged from the compiler group, who clearly used symbols/elements in places that they aren't really called for. I find that interesting. Then they corrected their…mistake? when they crafted the lang model but did not try to correct it within the guts of the compiler itself. I find that, too, interesting.